# WPF enable/disable button depending on value

Tags: button

i would like to enable/disable buttons according to the current active userlevel. i have a property in the MV for the current userlevel:

```
public int CurrentUserLevel
    {
        get { return _CurrentUserLevel; }
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentUserLevel == value)
                return;
            _CurrentUserLevel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUserLevel");
        }
    }
```

how can i enable/disable the button if this value is >=x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a property in your ViewModel, for which the Button's `IsEnabled` property can bind to.  Make sure that the new property's `PropertyChanged` event is raised whenever the `CurrentUserLevel` is changed.

```
public int CurrentUserLevel
{
    get { /*...*/ }
    set
    {
        /*...*/
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUserLevel");
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsAllowedToDoSomething"); //dependant property
    } 
}

public bool IsAllowedToDoSomething
{
    get { return CurrentUserLevel > 1; }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAllowedToDoSomething}" Content="Click me!" />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. so if i have 5 userlevels (1 to 5), i'll need to create 5 properties right? for each level one.

Comment: One for each type of binding you want to create on a Button, yes.  MVVM ViewModels contain a lot of these "helper" properties, which make binding from the View more natural.

Comment: Perhaps we can use [binding converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter?view=winrt-19041) and a single property instead of secondary properties. Converters accept [a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converterparameter?view=winrt-19041), so maybe a single converter will be required.